# common.api.soap.wsdl.Address used in expression: allacc.ShippingAddress

Tags: apex, visualforce

Why I'm getting the error, I have `ShippingAddress`field in the SOQL

> Unsupported type: common.api.soap.wsdl.Address used in expression:
>   allacc.ShippingAddress

```
<apex:pageblock id="allacc" title="Available Accounts">
       <apex:pageblocktable id="allacc" value="{!AllAccounts}" var="allacc">
            <apex:column headervalue="Set as Primary">                    
               <apex:actionsupport action="{!selectacc}" event="onclick" rerender="consel,allacc">  
                <input type="radio" name = "selectedAccount"/>                    
                    <apex:param name="conid" value="{!allacc.Id}">
                </apex:param></apex:actionsupport>  
            </apex:column>    
            <apex:column headervalue="Account Name">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!allacc.Name}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column> 
            <apex:column headervalue="Account Number">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!allacc.AccountNumber}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
            <apex:column headervalue="ShippingAddress">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!allacc.ShippingAddress}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  

        </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageblock>
```

Controller:

```
 public List<account> getAllAccounts()
 {
    List<account> allacc = [select id, name, AccountNumber,ShippingAddress from Account limit 10];
    return allacc;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Account.ShippingAddress` is an example of [Address Compound Fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm). As a convenience you can query all the individual values in one go using the compound name but to output the fields you have to output the individual `Street`, `City`, `State` etc fields in your Visualforce.